# PHP namespace syntax

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and would appreciate some help with namespaces.
I have a class and it's declared as:

```
namespace P3;
class CardstreamCodingStandard_Sniffs_Classes_ClassDeclarationSniff {
}
```

Now i want to implement an interface called `CodeSniffer_Sniff`. So i amended the class declaration as:

```
namespace P3;
class CardstreamCodingStandard_Sniffs_Classes_ClassDeclarationSniff extends CodeSniffer_Sniff  {
}
```

But when I run the code I get

```
Fatal error:  Interface 'P3\CodeSniffer_Sniff' not found in /root/qa/CardstreamCodingStandard/Sniffs/Classes/ClassDeclarationSniff.php
```

Please can someone explain what is going on? and what the correct syntax should be?

Thanks

Ok some more details
I have inherited this code that implements a sniff for phpcs

My class is declared as

```
namespace CardstreamCodingStandard\Sniffs\Classes;
class CardstreamCodingStandard_Sniffs_Classes_ClassDeclarationSniff implements PHP_CodeSniffer_Sniff {
}
```

when I run phpcs with this sniff then I get the error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'CardstreamCodingStandard\Sniffs\Classes\PHP_CodeSniffer_Sniff' not found in /root/qa/CardstreamCodingStandard/Sniffs/Classes/ClassDeclarationSniff.php on line 23
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpcs:0
PHP   2. PHP_CodeSniffer_CLI->runphpcs() /usr/bin/phpcs:25
PHP   3. PHP_CodeSniffer_CLI->process() /usr/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php:113
PHP   4. PHP_CodeSniffer->initStandard() /usr/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php:956
PHP   5. PHP_CodeSniffer->registerSniffs() /usr/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer.php:594
PHP   6. include_once() /usr/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer.php:1409
```

I hope this makes things clearer

Comment: This means you should first include the interface, because it can't find the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some details on how to use namespaces can be found at the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

In your case it seems you are using the same namespace.

To correctly use an interface, you have to implement it into your class.
The correct use would be the following:

```
Class Apple implements Fruit { ... }
```

More on interfaces and how to use them [can be found here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php).

You are using the `extends` keyword which is used for creating child classes of a parent class.

The php manual on parent and child classes (called inheritance) [has been linked here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php)

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this role :

```
file1:
        <?php 
          namespace foo;
          class Cat { 
            public function says(){
              echo 'meoow';
            }  
          } 
        ?>



        file2:
        <?php 
          include 'file1.php';
          use foo;
          class bar extends foo{
              //......
         }
```

more details: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: When I try this I get PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class CodeSniffer

Comment: if you have declared CodeSniffer_Sniff as an Interface  you should use implements keyword  not extends

Comment: can you show yor  file where you declare Interface?

Comment: Hossen is almost correct, you would only say: `class bar extends Cat implements CodeSniffer_Sniff` in file2

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement an interface, not extend. Try this:

```
class CardstreamCodingStandard_Sniffs_Classes_ClassDeclarationSniff implements CodeSniffer_Sniff  {
}
```

Comment: using the implements key word gives me the same errror

Comment: is `P3` in `namespace P3` your project root folder?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean by project root folder

Comment: try `use CodeSniffer_Sniff` in your `CardstreamCodingStandard_Sniffs_Classes_ClassDeclarationSniff` class